# How to pass information through several pages in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have two pages, my main index.html where I've put a call to action button to let the user to enter some text. When submitting it, I want the user to be redirected to the remaining part of the form, which is basically another form including the first parameter in the background. So, two different forms, but the second one sum up everything together and sends it to my Django server.

Therefore, I need the information from my main form, to be communicated to my second form. In php it would be easy with links, how should I process with Django ? I've seen server session storage but I'm sure there is a more efficient way like with JS ? I just need to communicate the information from the first page form, to the second page so it can send it to my server as a whole.

index.html

```
                <div class="form-container">
                    <form method="POST" action="form.html" class="form-post">
                        <input type="text" name="link" id="link" placeholder="Paste your link here" class="input-text">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="input-submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
```

form.html

```
how to retrieve the information id="link" from the index.html ?
```